# Solution space of a Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces, fundamental-solution

Generally, initial conditions to an $n^{th}$ order ODE involve initial conditions only involving derivatives up to the degree $ n-1 \  (like  \ y^{(n-1)}(0) \ =  \ A).$

Even a basis of the space of solutions to an ODE consists of solutions satisfying the following initial conditions, none of which contain any condition on $y_i^{(n)}(0)$.

$$y_1(0)=1,y_1'(0)=0,y_1''(0)=0,…,y_1^{(n−1)}(0)=0 \\ y_2(0)=0,y_2'(0)=1,y_2''(0)=0,…,y_2^{(n−1)}(0)=0 \\ y_3(0)=0,y_3'(0)=0,y_3''(0)=1,…,y_3^{(n−1)}(0)=0 \\ … \\ y_n(0)=0,y_n'(0)=0,y_n''(0)=0,…,y_n^{(n−1)}(0)=1$$

Now I understand that we can have only $n$ total initial conditions on the ODE, but is there any technical reason for skipping $y_i^{(n)}(0)$ instead of $y_i(0)$ when writing the initial conditions?

Can we have a basis to the solution space with conditions like

$$y_1'(0)=1,y_1''(0)=0,y_1'''(0)=0,…,y_1^{(n)}(0)=0 \\ y_2'(0)=0,y_2''(0)=1,y_2'''(0)=0,…,y_2^{(n)}(0)=0 \\ y_3'(0)=0,y_3''(0)=0,y_3'''(0)=1,…,y_3^{(n)}(0)=0 \\ … \\ y_n'(0)=0,y_n''(0)=0,y_n'''(0)=0,…,y_n^{(n)}(0)=1$$

Answer (score 1):

Your equation might be incompatible with that initial conditions. Consider for example 
$$
\begin{cases}
y''+y'=0 , & t>0\\ 
y''(0)=1 \\
y'(0)=0
\end{cases}
$$
If this problem had a solution, continuity would give at time $t=0$ the contradiction 
$$1=0.$$

Comment: Also even if you had $y'(0)=y''(0)=1$ which is compatible, solutions are allowed to differ by a constant, so there would be no uniqueness

Comment: I don't understand the part about a constant.

Comment: @Sidd: If you do not add the "@ellya" construct, he is not going to be notified of your comment and might never answer.

Comment: Anyway, once you find a solution $y(x)$ to the Cauchy problem with initial conditions $y'(0)=y''(0)=1$, any function $y(x)+C$, where $C$ is a constant, satisfies the same problem. So you do not have uniqueness of solutions.

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro: So is it right to say that the $n^{th}$ derivative term will have no constants and hence having a condition on it won't give us a unique solution?

Comment: @Sidd: No it is not correct. What we have done here, with this specific example, is showing that in general the Cauchy problem with a condition on the $n$th derivative is ill posed. Period.